# How to pass datatable as input to procedure in IIB?

Tags: ibm-integration-bus

in SQL Server I can create a procedure to receive a datatable as input instead of of primitive type, this way I can pass a list of values, like the example below.

```
--Create Type
CREATE TYPE dbo.NamesList
AS TABLE
(
  fullName VARCHAR(50)
);
--Create Procedure
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.DoSomethingWithNames
  @List AS dbo.NamesList READONLY
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  SELECT fullName FROM @List;
END

--Example of SQL Call
--Set variable values
DECLARE @NL NamesList;
INSERT @NL VALUES ('Bill'),('Michael'),('Paul'),('William'),('Kate')
--Call procedure
Exec DoSomethingWithNames @NL
```

On IBM IIB I can call stored procedures with a code like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetFiles (IN idFile INTEGER)
LANGUAGE DATABASE
DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1
EXTERNAL NAME "dbo.SP_S_FILE";
```

But I have no idea if it's possible to pass a datatable instead of primitive value and how to it. Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the [PASTHRU statement](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSMKHH_10.0.0/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/ak05100_.htm)?  I haven't tried doing what you're asking before, but the documentation sounds promising (assuming the limitations don't prevent you from using it).

> PASSTHRU can still be used to call stored procedures if:
>
> - Only input parameters can be used.
> - Only single result sets are supported.
>
> If you don't meet these criteria, use the CALL statement because PASSTHRU
>   imposes limitations (you cannot use output parameters, for example).